# why react native not release memory after component will Unmount?

Tags: react-native

I have an app that when a user clicks on a button, it displays content that includes photos, videos, animation, and the web view ... and then automatically returns to the first page after a period of time. But the amount of memory does not return to the former

before click => Memory is 38 MB
after content showed => Memory is 100 MB and never decrease even after 10 min

I haven't any event listener and just I have one settimeout which after that is finished I am sure the componentWillUnmount will run and clear (I put console.log in this component)

what should I do to release memory?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            program: false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                program: true
            })
        }, 10000);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.program == false) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Page>

                    </Page>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                this.props.navigation.navigate("receivepage")
                // null
            );

        }

    }
}

export default App;


class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("unmount")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{
                    width: 300, height: 600,
                    position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0,
                    zIndex: 0
                }}>
                    <WebView
                        source={{ uri: 'https://www.yahoo.com' }}
                    ></WebView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Page Class has content that includes photos, videos, animation, and the web view ... that in here just there is a URL
So when settimeout finished on the Page Class, the component will be unmounted and should memory release but it doesn't happen

Comment: Can you show your piece of code?

Comment: Please show the code involved not the app component's code, i guess here it's the page component that's missing

Comment: I edited the question and put a piece of my code that also not working